# Vim: Use different ~/.vim/plugin/ directories for different versions of vim?

Tags: unix, vim

Like many of you, my custom Vim configuration is stored in my `~/.vimrc`, with the plugins, colors, etc. stored under `~/.vim/plugins`, `~/.vim/colors`, etc.

I want to share a single Vim configuration among many servers. Some of these servers run Vim 7, some run the older Vim 6. Most Vim plugins are intended for Vim 7, but older versions still exist for those of us on older systems. See [DirDiff](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=102) for an example.

If I am on a system which runs Vim 6, how can I configure Vim to only use Vim 6-compatible plugins?

I was thinking about storing older plugins in a subdirectory like `~/.vim/plugins6/` and keep the Vim plugins in `~/.vim/plugins`, but then how can I tell Vim6 to ignore `~/.vim/plugins` and use `~/.vim/plugins6` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your .vimrc, you'll have to check vim version, and update your &runttimepath in consequence.

EDIT:

My mistake. Vim directories architecture is hard-coded. Instead, you should have a `~/.vim6` directory that has symlinks to all `´/.vim` directories but `plugin/` and `after/plugin`, and you should add the following in your .vimrc:

```
if version < 700
   let &rtp=substitute(&rtp, '\.vim', '&6', 'g')
endif
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but it seems that Vim is picking up the plugin in ~/.vim/plugin , not ~/.vim/plugin6 (See my code, and the results at http://stackoverflow.pastebin.com/4jVT1wsR ). I think I'm close, however.

Comment: Your update works great. Thanks! I now have a .vim and a .vim6 directory, and update the Vim realtimepath (rtp) as appropriate.

Comment: Checking `v:version` is more *proper*. `version` is left for legacy compatibility. Also note that for Vim 7.3, `v:version` == `703`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your vimrc check the vim version, then source all the plugins from a specific folder.

```
if &loadplugins
  if v:version >= 700
    runtime! plugin7/*.vim
    runtime! plugin7/**/*.vim
  elseif v:version >= 600
    runtime! plugin6/*.vim
    runtime! plugin6/**/*.vim
  endif
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do it like this:

```
HOME=<customdir1> <vim binary version1>

HOME=<customdir2> <vim binary version2>
```

**HOME** is an environment variable here. For convenience you could wrap these calls into shell scripts.

This general approach often works.